# Mobile Facebook App Request Dialogue scroll/select issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

[image]

When you invoke the App Request Dialogue in a mobile interface (see attached image), you can't scroll down through your friend list without also selecting the Friend where your finger hits the screen.

eg

If I start scrolling (by placing my finger on the screen as 'Robert Devereux'), Robert Devereux is selected into the To: field.

The only way this works is if you scroll at the very edge of the screen.

Has anyone found a way to overcome this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Facebook bug, which has now been resolved.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/157829941055467